# heroku ECONNREFUSED: connect ECONNREFUSED for all run command

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm receiving ECONNREFUSED for `heroku run any_command_here`. Heroku login is successful. Other heroku commands are successful as well (apps,releases, sharing). App is running. I can even access heroku logs. Ubuntu version is 14.04.

Comment: I think your question _might_ be better suited for ServerFault

Comment: @Aperçu. Unfortunately there is no message to help. It just prints  ▸    ECONNREFUSED: connect ECONNREFUSED +server_ip:5000 and that all. I can see that I've been added to this app. My ssh key is added to heroku account. I can see logs for this app, but I can't evaluate run command =( I removed ubuntu heroku toolbelt and reinstall it as Standalone, but this didn't help.

Comment: Is it possible you have a firewall or proxy server blocking a connection?

Comment: @JamesWard Can you be a little bit more specific? I've checked this sudo ufw status it returns Status: inactive

Comment: You can see that the `heroku-run` plugin in the CLI is probably attaching to a non-standard port: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-run/blob/master/commands/run.js#L103
You probably have a firewall or something between you and that server that is blocking access.  You could file an issue on that project.

Comment: BTW: You can see an example URL in the Heroku Platform API docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno

Comment: Just wondering, does "server_ip" (as in "+server_ip:5000") begin with "192.168"? If so, then it's probably an external firewall (between your computer and the internet; aka inside your network).

Comment: @Coder256 . Thanks for pointing thing about server ip. It was external firewall. Not on my local machine, but in office network. You can write answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Did you find any solution for running commands (without `:detach`) even when behind a firewall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be an external firewall - a firewall between your computer and the internet (inside your network). Chances are that if the `server_ip` begins with `192.168`, then that is the case.

Comment: how can i solve this problem? how can i disable such firewall? my address is 127.0.0.1

Comment: You can't disable the firewall, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694960/4747193).

Answer (score 13):

Try running

> heroku run:detached *your command here*

and it will fly, if the issue was the firewall.

Comment: Allows commands to execute, but `stdout` of these commands won't be attached to your terminal, so you can't open an interactive shell with `heroku run bash`.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy